# How to access terraform variables in python canary code?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have created an `aws_synthetics_canary`.  I want to access `LOGIN_ID` and `PASSWORD` terraform variables in python canary script. I have tried this

```
run_config {
    environment_variables = {
      LOGIN_ID = var.LOGIN_ID
      PASSWORD = var.PASSWORD
    }
```

On running the code with above terraform snippet it's showing error

```
 Error: Unsupported argument
│ 
│   on modules/canary/canary.tf line 44, in resource "aws_synthetics_canary" "sre-canary":
│   44:     environment_variables = {
│ 
│ An argument named "environment_variables" is not expected here
```

Can anyone please guide me on doing this? Thank you :)

Comment: What is `resource "aws_synthetics_canary" "sre-canary"`?

Comment: That's the syntax for creating the canary in terraform and sre-canary is the name that I have given .

Comment: You have to show full code.

Comment: Well, that should be pretty easy to guess based on the error output. But there is no `environment_variables` block expected: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp%20%20/aws/latest/docs/resources/synthetics_canary.

Comment: Yeah I understood the error. But in the official documentation it was mentioned to use enviornment_variables

Comment: The solution mentioned in the link mentioned by Marko doesn't work. I have checked it before posting the question itself. I found the solution

Comment: Marko did you even try the solution you mentioned?Incase if it's working for you I would love to know my mistake?Because for me it didn't work.

Comment: No, I haven't tried and that's my bad, but you haven't posted the entire code so that was my first assumption. You can answer your question so the others can see it as well.

Comment: Yeah, my bad. I will post it clearly next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/17948#issuecomment-1023517058).

We have to create a null resource which will execute `aws synthetics update-canary` command upon updation of certain paramters which can be mentioned in the `trigger` block. In `provisioner` block we have to set the command to be executed.

```
locals {
  canary_name                   = "foo"
  canary_timeout_in_seconds     = 30
  canary_memory_limit_in_mb     = 960
  canary_active_tracing_enabled = false
  canary_environment_variables  = { FOO: "BAR" }
  set_canary_run_config_command = "aws synthetics update-canary --name ${local.canary_name} --run-config '${jsonencode({TimeoutInSeconds: local.canary_timeout_in_seconds, MemoryInMB: local.canary_memory_limit_in_mb, ActiveTracing: local.canary_active_tracing_enabled, EnvironmentVariables: local.canary_environment_variables })}'"
}

resource "aws_synthetics_canary" "healthchecks" {
  name                      = local.canary_name
  start_canary              = true
  s3_bucket                 = aws_s3_bucket_object.canary_script.bucket
  s3_key                    = aws_s3_bucket_object.canary_script.key
  artifact_s3_location      = "s3://${aws_s3_bucket.canary_bucket.id}/"
  execution_role_arn        = aws_iam_role.canary.arn
  handler                   = "apiCanaryBlueprint.handler"
  runtime_version           = "syn-nodejs-puppeteer-3.3"

  schedule {
    expression = "rate(1 hour)"
  }

  run_config {
    active_tracing      = local.canary_active_tracing_enabled
    memory_in_mb        = local.canary_memory_limit_in_mb
    timeout_in_seconds  = local.canary_timeout_in_seconds
  }
}

resource "null_resource" "add_environment_variables_to_canary" {
  # Run this command again whenever any of the run-config parameters change
  triggers = {
    canary_active_tracing_enabled = local.canary_active_tracing_enabled
    canary_memory_limit_in_mb     = local.canary_memory_limit_in_mb
    canary_timeout_in_seconds     = local.canary_timeout_in_seconds
    # Trigger values must be strings (or implicitly coerced into strings, like bools), so turn env vars into a string like FOO=bar,FIZZ=buzz
    canary_environment_variables  = join(",", [ for key, value in local.canary_environment_variables: "${key}=${value}" ])
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = local.set_canary_run_config_command
  }

  depends_on = [ aws_synthetics_canary.healthchecks ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the version of the AWS provider that you are using by running `terraform version` after running `terraform init`.  The `environment_variable` key in the `run_config` block was added in version `4.5.0` of the AWS provider.  If you're referring to the documentation, it'll show you the latest version of the provider by default, which is 4.13.0 at the time of this posting.

[v4.5.0 provider documentation.](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/4.5.0/docs/resources/synthetics_canary#run_config)

If upgrading the version of the AWS provider from what you are currently using to at least 4.5.0 is an option, then you will be able to use the `environment_variables` block.  If not, you'll have to find another solution.

Comment: Is v4.5.0 released?I think it's not yet released. I have actually found a solution in the internet which works even for versions < 4.5.0. I will upload it as soon as possible

Comment: Yes, version 4.5.0 is released, the latest is 4.13.0 linked here: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs.  Congrats on the alternate solution, it is often not an option to upgrade versions.